# Searching for a StringVar within a List

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm creating a log in system and trying to keep entries when I have an Error message appear. I use a StringVar to store the entries so after I destroy the entry box and remake it the entries are still there. However, when I try to use an if statement to find the StringVar in a list of usernames and passwords that I have it keeps saying that the Username doesn't exist when I know that it does. Any ideas on how to keep the entries and not use a StringVar or how to search a list for a StringVar?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Login_sys(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Login_sys,self).__init__(master)
        self.userlist=['user1','user2']
        self.passlist=['pass1','pass2']
        self.grid()
        self.initial()
    def initial(self):
        self.CurrentError=('')
        self.user_E=StringVar()
        self.user_E.set('')
        self.pass_E=StringVar()
        self.pass_E.set('')
        self.title_lbl=Label(self,text='Welcome',fg='blue')
        self.title_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.login_bttn=Button(self,text='  Log In  ',fg='red',command=self.login)
        self.login_bttn.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.reg_bttn=Button(self,text='  Register  ',fg='red',command=self.register)
        self.reg_bttn.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
    def login(self):
        self.title_lbl.destroy()
        self.login_bttn.destroy()
        self.reg_bttn.destroy()
        self.LI_title_lbl=Label(self,text='Log In',fg='blue')
        self.LI_title_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.user_lbl=Label(self,text='Username:',fg='red')
        self.user_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.userE=Entry(self,text=self.user_E)
        self.userE.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.pass_lbl=Label(self,text='Password:',fg='red')
        self.pass_lbl.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.passE=Entry(self,show='*')
        self.passE.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.Confirm_bttn=Button(self,text='Confirm',fg='blue',command=self.login_confirm)
        self.Confirm_bttn.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.Back_bttn=Button(self,text='Back',fg='black',command=self.login_back)
        self.Back_bttn.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.CurrentError_lbl=Label(self,text=self.CurrentError,fg='red')
        self.CurrentError_lbl.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
    def login_back(self):
        self.LI_title_lbl.destroy()
        self.user_lbl.destroy()
        self.userE.destroy()
        self.pass_lbl.destroy()
        self.passE.destroy()
        self.Confirm_bttn.destroy()
        self.Back_bttn.destroy()
        self.CurrentError_lbl.destroy()
        self.initial()
    def login_confirm(self):
        self.user_E.set(self.userE.get())
        self.pass_E.set(self.passE.get())
        if self.user_E in self.userlist:
            if self.pass_E in self.passlist:
                if self.passlist.index(self.pass_E)==self.userlist.index(self.user_E):
                    self.logged_in()
                else:
                    self.CurrentError='The Password Entered \nis Incorrect'
                    self.Login_Error()
            else:
                self.CurrentError='The Password Entered \nis Incorrect'
                self.Login_Error()
        else:
            self.CurrentError='Username does not exist'
            self.Login_Error()
    def Login_Error(self):
        self.LI_title_lbl.destroy()
        self.user_lbl.destroy()
        self.userE.destroy()
        self.pass_lbl.destroy()
        self.passE.destroy()
        self.Confirm_bttn.destroy()
        self.Back_bttn.destroy()
        self.CurrentError_lbl.destroy()
        self.login()
```

Comment: You are looking for *the StringVars themselves* in your lists, rather than the text held by the StringVars (which you retrieve via `.get()`).  Nothing in your code is benefiting from the use of StringVars, anyway.

Comment: The only reason I am using the StringVars is to keep the text in the entry boxes when the confirm button is pressed

Comment: You could just as easily keep the text in an ordinary Python variable.  The only time you need the special Tkinter var types is for the `textvariable=` or similar option of some widgets, that allows the widget state to be directly tied to the var (Python variables don't support this).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
        if self.user_E in self.userlist:
            if self.pass_E in self.passlist:
```

with:

```
        if self.user_E.get() in self.userlist:
            if self.pass_E.get() in self.passlist:
```

As `self.userlist` and `self.passlist` are string object lists whereas `self.user_E` and `self.pass_E` are `StringVar` objects, you must first convert them to strings if you want to see their strings are contained in a string object list.